# Where to put cerificate file using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate

I'm working with **PHP cURL** function and after some problems with https now everything works fine. But I have a question about **CURLOPT_CAINFO** and where to put the certificate file.

I have to put the "cert.crt" files outside the web root directory (for example: the root server) or okay if I put it under my site folder (for example: " www.myexamplesite.examp/**cert.crt**") ?

Thank You